# Send date field as empty in response instead of setting to null and not sending in response

Tags: java, date, jackson, null, response

I am currently dealing with a scenario where in the DB I have a date column that has NULL values set.  When I test the below code and get my response, the field is not even coming in my response when that value is NULL.  How can I automatically send the field in the response and handle the NULL scenario, sending a blank value such as an empty string?  The field is required to send in the response (userIndDate which is a java.util.Date object).  I am using jackson to serialize the data.  I have not include my repo which is doing the db->object mapping just to condense the code.  Below is the code snippet?

```
var newResponse =  SearchResponse.builder()
            .item((Integer) row[0]).itemDesc((String) row[1])
            .loc(String.valueOf((Integer ) row[2])).locDesc((String) row[3])
            .ase((BigDecimal) (row[4]))
            .aseStartDate((row[5] != null ? (java.util.Date)(row[5]) : null))
            .indDate(row[6] != null ? (java.util.Date)(row[6]) : null)
            .userIndDate((row[7] != null ? (java.util.Date)(row[7]) : null))
            .seasonalProfileName((String) (row[8]))
            .build();

        resultStream.add(newResponse);
        return newResponse;
```

Response is below when the userIndDate column is NULL at db end (i.e. missing in the response):

```
{
    "searchResponse": [
        {
            "loc": "1",
            "item": 2,
            "itemDesc": "someItemDesc",
            "locDesc": "someLocDesc",
            "ase": 1.00000000000000000,
            "aseStartDate": "2023-07-01",
            "indDate": "2023-12-30"
        }
    ],
    "message": "",
    "warning": "",
    "responseCode": "0"
}
```

Comment: What are you using to serialize the data as json?

Comment: We’re missing some context here. Which `SearchResponse` class is that? It seems you are neither using JDBC nor Hibernate for your database access, so what *are* you using? Also what prevents you from handling the absence of the field the same way you would have handled null?

Comment: Not what you asked, is there a way you can avoid using `java.util.Date`? Java’s `Date` classes were poorly designed and are long outdated, For a date use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Jackson for serialisation, putting `JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)` on the `SearchResponse` class will always include all the class properties no matter their values. Thus, including the null values as well.

Comment: that worked!  Thank you for the suggestion.  I've marked this as the answer as it pertains to Jackson which is being used for serializing the data, and also for simplicity in the solution that is very useful.